# How to dynamically change the bing website icon on google

Tags: android, kotlin

```
   arr.add(
        SearchEngine(
            0,
            context.getString(R.string.google),
            "https://www.google.com/search?q="
               
        )
    )
```

I have such a code that performs a Google search. And I also have a link https://t.supersimplesearch1.com/searchm?q= which does the Bing search, like this, somehow I need to make the Bing icon change to the Google icon.

I have a browser and this arr to open in different browsers , the example given is a google search, but I have an affiliate link that opens bing by default, it is already involved in the code, but now I need to make it so that it opens not bing but google

I have searched for information on various sources , but I have not found anything like this yet

Comment: Not sure what `arr` is but if you redirect to bing, you're gonna get a bing icon.

Comment: I need to change "https://www.google.com/search?q=" on https://t.supersimplesearch1.com/searchm?q= but so that google opens

Comment: Is that (supersimplesearch) your website?

Comment: It seems to be, but my employer said that I need to "dynamically" change bing to Google, in the code

Comment: And what is meant by dynamically changing it?

Comment: I don't understand, my employers can't explain it to me normally, but I think it might be better to just redirect requests to Google through this link and open everything in Google too

Comment: So change the website? If you don't understand what your employer means, you should ask them and not people on the internet.

Comment: I threw a question here because I didn't understand what a dynamic change is, suddenly there would be something that I didn't know. And the employer just stands on his own, and does not explain anything, so I'm sorry

Comment: The word 'dynamically' could mean a lot of things - it could mean your app is supposed to replace it at runtime or your website - either using a redirect or JS - or something completely different.

Comment: The application should replace at runtime

Comment: Then...change your application I guess? For example, you could just replace the URL string (e.g. `searchURL.replaceFirst("t.supersimplesearch1.com/searchm?q=","www.google.com/search?q=")`)?

Comment: then the search bar reflects /www.google.com/search?q=example

Comment: Yes, it does. What else is it supposed to be?

Comment: it is reflected not in the full search bar but in the place where the user enters his question